# How to spoof a search engine bot with curl?

Tags: curl, search-engine, bots

How do I make a request to a website using cURL and make the website believe that I am a search engine.

Comment: Set the user agent using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)');`

Comment: https://github.com/izniburak/google-bot-curl/blob/master/google-bot.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set your user-agent to Googlebot's (more info on the exact user-agents used on [Google's KB](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1061943)):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)');
```

This might not always work though! Some websites may choose to [Reverse DNS check](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80553) anyone claiming to be Googlebot.

Comment: or using the command line option: `-A "'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)')"` when running from a terminal

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to access the html data in a website protected by cloudflare?